# One API call vs multiple

Tags: node.js, backend

I have a process in the back-end which will take take on average 30 to 90 seconds to complete.

Is it better to have a font-end react app make ONE API call and wait for back-end to complete and process and return the data. Or is it better to have the front-end make multiple calls, lets say every 2 seconds to check if the process and complete and get back the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not good to make a single API call and wait for 30-90 seconds to get a response. Instead send a response immediately mentioning that the request is successful and would be processed.

Now you can use web sockets or library like socket.io so that the server can communicate directly to the client once the requested processing is complete.

The multiple API calls to check if server is done or server has any new message is called polling and is not much efficient but it is still required in old browsers which don't support web sockets. Socket.io support s polling automatically in old browsers.

But, yes if you want you can do multiple calls to check if server is done processing, but I would prefer server to communicate back to the client , it is better.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid approaches. You could also report status changes with websocket so there's no need for polling.

If you do want to go the polling route, the general recommendation is to:

- Return `202 accepted` from your long-running process endpoint.
- Also return a `Link` header with a url to where the status of the process can be read.
- The client can then follow that client and ping it every x seconds.